# How to create scatterplot from one variable splitted to x and y axes by factor?

Tags: r, ggplot2, dplyr

I'm a beginner in R
I guess my question is too basic but I stacked with that for hours.
I have the dataset:

```
cstock:
'data.frame':   895 obs. of  33 variables:
$ ID    : chr  "1" "2" "3" "4" ...
$ plot  : Factor w/ 42 levels "D1","D10","D11",..: 1 1 1 1 1 12 12 12 12 12 ...
$ type  : Factor w/ 2 levels "litter","soil": 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 ...
$ mxdpt : num  5.12 5.62 5.25 5.75 6.62 ...
```

each 'plot' has 5 'mxdpt' values for 'type:soil' and 5 values for 'type:litter'.

I want to create a scatterplot of 'mxdpt' splitted to x and y by factor 'type' where each point on the scatterplot is a mean value of 'mxdpt' for each plot for factor 'soil' for y axis and another is the mean value of 'mxdpt' for each plot for factor 'litter' for x axis .
I guess that dyplr might help before ggplot
but I'm just a beginner in R.
Sorry and thank you for the answers.

Here is what I've tried:

```
cstock%>%
    ggplot(aes(x=mxdpt, y=mxdpt, color=type))
+stat_summary(fun = mean, geom = 'point', pch=15)+stat_summary(fun = mean, geom ='line')+stat_summary(fun.data = mean_se, geom="errorbar", width= 0.1)
```

And what I've got:

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/hWEwm.png)

I want this:

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ElrKg.jpg)

Comment: best in those cases to summarise the data beforehand, e.g. `library(tidyverse); iris %>% group_by(Species) %>% summarise(m_SL = mean(Sepal.Length), m_PL = mean(Petal.Length)) %>% ggplot() + geom_point(aes(m_SL, m_PL))`. this is just with a different data set and you’ll need to adjust that to your data accordingly

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I agree with @tjebo to summarise your data before passing it to `ggplot2`. However, as you want to make a scatter plot of your types you need an additional reshape step using e.g. `tidyr::pivot_wider` so that you get a column with the mean values for `soil` and a column for `litter`.

Using some fake random example data:

```r
library(ggplot2)
library(dplyr, warn=FALSE)
library(tidyr)

set.seed(123)
n <- 895

cstock <- data.frame(
  ID = seq(n),
  plot = factor(sample(paste0("D", 1:42), n, replace = TRUE)),
  type = factor(sample(c("litter", "soil"), n, replace = TRUE)),
  mxdpt = runif(n, 5, 7)
)

cstock %>% 
  group_by(plot, type) %>% 
  summarise(mxdpt = mean(mxdpt, na.rm = TRUE)) %>% 
  pivot_wider(names_from = type, values_from = mxdpt) %>% 
  ggplot(aes(litter, soil)) +
  geom_point()
#> `summarise()` has grouped output by 'plot'. You can override using the
#> `.groups` argument.
```

[image]

Comment: great thanks for your reply. I didn't even look in that direction.
By the way, executing this code produces an Error:
'cstock%>%
  select(plot, mxdpt, type)%>%#select a given columns
  group_by(plot, type)%>%#grouping by given factors
  summarise(mxdpt=mean(mxdpt, na.rm=T))%>%
  pivot_wider(names_from = type, values_from = mxdpt)%>%
  ggplot(aes(litter, soil))+
  geom_point()'
Error in `pivot_wider()`:
! Can't subset columns that don't exist.
✖ Column `type` doesn't exist.

Comment: Hm. Don't see any reason which might cause the issue. Best is to break your pipeline in steps, which you can run run by one, i.e. run only the code up to and including the summarise. Check your data and whether it contains a column named type.

Comment: Here is the full project on the GitHub https://github.com/EastBoreal/CSTOCK1/commit/d7e3c5734e8143177d75e62241d0ed31e697a966

Comment: pivot_wider works correctly if applied to the initial data set, but if I put for example 'select' function prior to pivot it creates a tibble of correct dimensions BUT with values = NULL
cstock%>%
  select(plot, mxdpt, type)%>%
  pivot_wider(names_from = type, values_from = mxdpt)

Comment: Hi Simon. I had a look at your Rmd on GitHub. Lots of packages. The issue is most likely related to the fact that you use the `plyr` package which results in (namespace) conflicts with `dplyr`. To check that try with `dplyr::select` so that you get the right function. For this reason it is recommended to load `plyr` before `dplyr`. But ask yourself whether it is really needed (plyr is retired and most or all things can be done using dplyr, tidyr, ...).

Comment: Thanks a lot, @stefan I restart R, and attach only these 3 libraries.
So, now trying these:
cstock%>%
  filter(vars(mxdpt), all_vars(!is.na(.)))%>
 I get an error with the filter function Error in `filter()`:
ℹ In argument: `vars(mxdpt)`.
Caused by error:
! `..1` must be a logical vector, not a <quosures/list> object.
Backtrace:
 1. cstock %>% filter(vars(mxdpt), all_vars(!is.na(.)))
 9. dplyr:::dplyr_internal_error(...)
Error in filter(., vars(mxdpt), all_vars(!is.na(.))) :
Caused by error:
! `..1` must be a logical vector, not a <quosures/list> object.

Comment: Haha. `vars()` is well, retired too since and never worked with `filter`. It was meant to be used in `filter_at`. But it is not needed as you want to filter for just one column, i.e. try `filter(!is.na(mxdpt))`. If you really have to check multiple variables then check `across` and `if_all` or `if_any`.

Comment: Great thanks, @stefan! The problem was with a bunch of conflicting packages. However, your code is now completely performed with the proper result!